# Populate vertical table in JSP

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, jsp, spring-data

I'm new in web development, I need your help & suggestion to make with easy ways vertical table in JSP or Javascript from the JSON data, like below image:

[image]

This is for table from database:

[image]

And here for the JSON data:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "shipping" : [ {
      "dayCd" : "1",
      "shiftCd" : "1",
      "qty" : "40",
      "productName" : "Prod1",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/shipping/1001"
        },
        "shipping" : {
          "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/shipping/1001"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "dayCd" : "2",
      "shiftCd" : "1",
      "qty" : "40",
      "productName" : "Prod1",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/shipping/1002"
        },
        "shipping" : {
          "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/shipping/1002"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "dayCd" : "3",
      "shiftCd" : "1",
      "qty" : "40",
      "productName" : "Prod1",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/shipping/1003"
        },
        "shipping" : {
          "href" : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/shipping/1003"
        }
      }
..........
```

Comment: is there any efforts of yours? so that we can know the exact problem you are facing and get to specific point to help you out. Cause you will find similar example online for this kind of task.

Comment: btw, you can use `jstl` to populate your data, instead of using `JSON`

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you (want to) do, **show your code** instead (what have you tried so far).